# React-Twitter-Login Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, twitter

m trying to implement twitter signup with react-twitter-login, but its giving error m not getting why error is occur. its react library .

```
import React, { useState } from "react";;
import TwitterLogin from "react-twitter-login";

const SocialLoginReact = () => {
     
  const authHandler = (err, data) => {
    console.log(err, data);
  };  
  return (
        <div> 
          <TwitterLogin
            authCallback={authHandler}
            consumerKey={"0MF*****9dDn2"}
            consumerSecret={
              "V2VMLYLb***************8bfP4eei"
            }
            callbackUrl={"http://localhost:3000/"}
          />
        </div>
  );
};

export default SocialLoginReact;
```

[This is error m getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmX0d.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmX0d.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVkzK.png)

this is code that i took from react-twitter-login

Comment: Look at the network tab in your browser, you will see a request in red to twitter, what does it say?

Comment: its showing request_token 401 fetch

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem/error description here instead of pasting screenshots.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience,  but this all what i got. simple code m trying to implement react-twitter-login passing values and running it and its giving error.